# jQuery Cycle hide prev/next navigation if there is only one slide.

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin to cycle through multiple divs in a container. All is working well the only functionality that I would like to add that I can't seem to find an option for with in the plugin is the ability to hide both buttons if there is only one slide present with in the container. My current code is this:

```
    //Goal summary page cycler
    $('#showGoal').after('<div id="nav">')
                .cycle({
                    fx: 'scrollHorz',
                    speed:300,
                    prev: '#goalPrev',
                    next: '#goalNext',
                    timeout: 0,
                    pager: '#nav',                        
                    after: onAfter, 
                    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
                        return'<a href="#"></a>';
                    }
                });

            // call back to remove buttons on first and last slide / adjust height of container
            function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
                var index = opts.currSlide;
                $('#goalPrev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                $('#goalNext')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();

                //get the height of the current slide
                var $ht = $(this).height();
                //animates the container's height to that of the current slide 
                $(this).parent().animate({ height: $ht });
            }
```

I'm guessing I can either check the index and remove them both that way or possibly do something along the lines of an if statement for example (pseudo code) :

```
    var index = this.index();
    var numOfSlides = 0;

    if ( numOfSlide < index ) {
       //hide the buttons 
   }
   else
   {
       //show the buttons
   }
```

Thanks for any possible help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach recommended by the plugin author is to hide the buttons using Javascript:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cycle-plugin-hide-prev-next

Comment: Wow, you must be some sort of mind reader. After all these months I just had an issue TODAY where the method I was using with css to handle this was being problematic and I was looking for a new solution. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it already work?  If you only have one slide then your onAfter function should take care of it.  With one slide your index is always 0.  Your opts.slideCount - 1 would also be zero because you would have one slide minus one.

Edit:

But as stated below, onAfter may need to be called after the page loads because when dealing with one slide the function may not be getting called.

Comment: Logically you would think so but for what ever reason it isn't and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: i would do some troubleshooting, like printing out the index, printing out the slideCount, and making sure it works at the ends of multiple slides

Comment: If there are multiple slides then the arrows disappear accordingly once you reach the end of the slide deck in that direction. But Yea I'm going to play around with it a little more. I just haven't come across anything that has been problematic yet.

Comment: what might be happening is that it only runs after the first time it is clicked.  so you might just need to run onAfter after the window loads

Comment: ...hmm that's true, didn't think about that. Going to give it a shot and see what happens. Good thought!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved and I feel like an idiot for missing it, You have to set the display of the arrows to none initially.